# Objective-c refer variable outside of block

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to refer variable which I define inside of if block at outside of if else block.  How can I?  If it can't be, do I have to write same long code (they can't be function or method) inside if block and else block?

```
if (aTrack.compilation)
{
    NSString *artistName = NSLocalizedString(@"compilations", @"");
}
else
{
    NSString *artistName = aTrack.artist
}

NSLog(@"%@",artistName);
```

Comment: expect the issue you should add ';' at the end of this line: `NSString *artistName = aTrack.artist`

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @nickfalk and @CRD posted is good but you can also (for such easy statements) use a ternary operator which in this case will look like this:

```
NSString *artistName = aTrack.compilation ? NSLocalizedString(@"compilations", @""): aTrack.artist;

NSLog(@"%@",artistName);
```

It is a matter of style but I would go this way for this simple example as my code is in one line

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of an ordinary (non static) variable declared in a block is just that block, any nested blocks, etc. This is part of the standard lifetime and visibility rules of (Objective-)C(++).

Just declare the variable *before* the `if`/`else` and assign values to it in each block.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  This solves my question, but still Xcode warns me the variable is not used in if/else block.  Can I ignore it?

Comment: The comment above is my mistake.  ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
NSString *artistName;

if (aTrack.compilation){
    artistName = NSLocalizedString(@"compilations", @"");
} else {
    artistName = aTrack.artist;
}

NSLog(@"%@",artistName);
```

Also have a look at CRD's reply as this is really basic knowledge and you really need to understand this. (Also, as viperking noticed in my example, there was a terminating semicolon missing in your original code...)

Viperking has a nice example using the the ternary operator. It might be a bit alien at first but is rather nice when you wrap your head around it. a third solution would be

```
NSString *artistName = aTrack.artist;

if (aTrack.compilation){
    artistName = NSLocalizedString(@"compilations", @"");
} 

NSLog(@"%@",artistName);
```

For more complex scenarios I would advice against it, but for an example with two possible cases and one single string it would be quite legible. I'd also advice using `nil` rather than an empty-string for the `localizedString` comment.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  This solves my question, but still Xcode warns me the variable is not used in if/else block.  Can I ignore it?

Comment: About semicolon, so sorry this was my easy mistake.

Comment: What is the warning exactly?

Comment: Sorry,it's my mistake.  I declared variable twice, before if/else block and inside if/else block.  So sorry.